# how create windows global variables in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, global-variables, static-variables

(at first i say that use C# with winform and .Net Framework4)

is there any way to create a class library (dll) with static variables and get variable from some programs as concurrent (and static variables does not reset for each program).

**more explain:**

for example i create a dll with static variables and install on GAC then add to reference of tow my program.

now i want set variables in Program1 and get variables on Program2.

how can do that?

Comment: You can't do that.  Learn about IPC (especially WCF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you can accomplish by

1. storing value in a storage accessible from different programs
2. using some process to process comunication mechanism (IPC mentioned by @SLaks)

storages that comes to my mind could are: database, windows registry, settings file

process to process communication may be WCF, or System.IO.Pipes, or others: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx

it all depends on your needs. Is it performace critical? Do you need to infrom the other process that value has changed, or the other process will just request the value? How many processes will access the value at the same time?